# Latex hyperref: get colours AND small capitals

Tags: hyperref, color

In `\hypersetup`, one can turn on/off the colours specified by `linkcolor` and `citecolor` with the help of the `colorlinks` option. One can also get small capitals style references by setting `frenchlinks=true`; however this latter only seems to have any effect if `colorlinks=false` is set.

Is it possible to get colours in links **and** small capitals? In particular I only want the citecolor to be gray, but that is also getting eliminated by setting `colorlinks` to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without hooks (for older installations) you can copy and combine the definitions of `frenchlinks` and `colorlinks` from the source file `hyperref.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[citecolor=gray]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\@pdfborder{0 0 0}%
\let\@pdfborderstyle\@empty
\def\Hy@colorlink#1{\begingroup\HyColor@UseColor#1%
\fontshape{\scdefault}\selectfont}%
\def\Hy@endcolorlink{\endgroup}%
\makeatother
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{A Link To A Website}

A citation: \cite{book-minimal}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(updated 2023-10)
`frenchlinks` replaces colors and that is quite hard coded in hyperref. Imho the option is rather odd.

With the new pdfmanagement you can do it as there are a number of hooks:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\ActivateGenericHook{hyp/link/link}
\AddToHook{hyp/link/link}{\scshape} %for other internal links
\AddToHook{hyp/link/cite}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}} %cite links
\begin{document}

\section{abc}\label{test}
\cite{citekey} 

\nameref{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Author]{citekey} some cite
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]